# Can someone explain my code to me

Tags: ruby

```
class Book
attr_accessor :title
    def title=(book_name)
        small_words = ["and", "in", "the", "of", "a", "an"]
        words = book_name.split(' ')
        words.each do |word| 
            small_words.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize! 
        end
        words[0].capitalize!
        @title = words.join(' ')
    end
end
```

So I've been learning Ruby and have been doing some Ruby tests. This one was to capitalize all book titles except for 'and', 'in', 'the' e.t.c. I understand most of it, except a couple things.
After reading the errors I could see that it wanted a class called Book, so I did that. Why is this needed?
And then  `attr_accessor :title` with `@title = words.join(' ')` at the end. I understand what they mean, but why are they needed?

Comment: Why do you think they are needed?

Comment: In my head as I see it, I've made a folder called Book and within that folder I have a file called title, that I can read and write on. Not sure if this is correct. The `@title` throws me off though. I get that the `@` links it to the `attr_accessor` but why not just `title = words.join('')`

Comment: Because `title = words.join(' ')` would be creating a __local__ variable title, instead of writing to that "file". You could also do `self.title = words.join(' ')`

Answer (score 3):

Basically let's say your input (book_name) is "the call of the cthulhu".

```
words = book_name.split(' ')
```

Splits into array of "the", "call", "of", "the", "cthulhu".

```
words.each do |word| 
    small_words.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize! 
end
```

Iterates over the array and capitalizes all the words *in place* except the words in small_words. Array now has "the", "Call", "of", "the", "Cthulhu".

```
words[0].capitalize!
```

Capitalizes the first word. So now the array has "The", "Call", "of", "the", "Cthulhu".

```
@title = words.join(' ')
```

Joins the array in one word (The Call of the Cthulhu) and sets it in the title -instance variable, which is referenced in Ruby with @ -syntax inside the class.

attr_accessor creates a setter and a getter for the title, which is needed when not inside the class.

```
x = book.title # x is now "The Call of the Cthulhu"
book.title = "New Title" # sets the title to a new String
```